# jquery-ui autocomplete with ASP MVC suggestions not displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have been trying to get a simple example of the jquery-ui autocomplete to work.   I have a controller setup to handle the query, and it returns the json that looks to be in order, but I am getting no suggestions showing up.

Here are the js libraries I am including:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js"></script>

 <link href="/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and here is the javascript and the form tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#organization").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Organization/OrganizationLookup',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        limit: 12,
                        q: request.term
                    }
                })
            },
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
</script> 

<div class="ui-widget"> 
    <label for="organization">Organization: </label> 
    <input id="organization" /> 
</div>
```

I get back a json response that looks reasonable from my controller:

```
[
  {
    "id":"Sector A",
    "value":"Sector A"
  },
  {
    "id":"Sector B",
    "value":"Sector B"
  },
  {
    "id":"Sector C",
    "value":"Sector C"
  }
]
```

id and value seem to be the default naming that autocomplete is looking for.

But I get no joy at all.   Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the issue here -- you should put css before javascript.  Always.

You are not doing anything with the return value.  You need to use a callback function to take that data and do something with it.  (The "success:" parameter, I believe).

Comment: You're right!

I had gone down the path of trying to get my json to match the data structure expected thinking that I wouldn't need to do any mapping (because my previous attempts at some more complex mapping had failed on me early on).  Different documentation I had read said that id/value or label/value were expected, but that didn't work...

Comment: nice, drat those blind alleys

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Hogan's suggestion, I added the following callback function to the success parameter, and I was good to go:

```
 success: function (data) {
                          response($.map(data, function (item) {
                              return {
                                  label: item.label,
                                  value: item.value
                              }
                          }))
```